# Uso del macro __LINE__ - C

Tags: c

Saludos!

Estoy realizando una funcion en C que permita obtener un registro mas detallado de lo que ocurre en el programa, algo parecido a un *debug*, pero tratando de resumir las cosas para el programador.

Me encontre con la documentacion del Preprocesador *CPP* (GNU/Linux) y alli indicaban los distintos *macros* y constantes que se pueden usar en nuestro programa de modo que tambien se pueden usar funciones y usar alli estos *macros*.

Gracias a esto realice el siguiente programa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Dump para variables */
#define dump(variable) {   \
    printf("La variable '%s' ocupa %d bytes\n", #variable, sizeof(variable)); \
}

/* Dump para funciones */
#define dumpf(){ \
    printf("Se llama a funcion %s()\n", __FUNCTION__); \
}

void funcion(int argumento){
    dumpf();
    printf("%d\n", argumento + argumento);
}

void sumar(int a, int b){
    dumpf();
    printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, (a+b));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    /* Variables */
    int variableINT   = 45;
    char variableCHAR = 'A';
    char *variablePTR = "Hola Mundo";

    /* Debug de Variables*/
    dump(variableINT);
    dump(variableCHAR);
    dump(variablePTR);

    /* Debug de Funcion*/
    funcion(10);
    sumar(5, 5);

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Este programa permite que sepamos el peso en *bytes* de una variable gracias a la funcion *dump()*, tambien permite saber que funcion estamos llamando por medio de la funcion *dumpf()*.

Hasta este punto, el resultado del programa en consola es:

> La variable 'variableINT' ocupa 4 bytes
>
> La variable 'variableCHAR' ocupa 1 bytes
>
> La variable 'variablePTR' ocupa 4 bytes
>
> Se llama a funcion funcion()
>
> 20
>
> Se llama a funcion sumar()
>
> 5 + 5 = 10

Despues de ello, para hacer un poco mas legible y mas facil de entender nuestro *"debug"*, quise añadir algo que indicara la linea en donde se estaba haciendo el llamado a la funcion, por lo tanto hice la siguiente modificacion en la funcion *dumpf()*:

```
/* Dump para funciones */
#define dumpf(){ \
    printf("Se llama a funcion %s() en la linea %d\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__); \
}
```

Agregué el macro ***LINE***, que en teoria nos indica la linea donde se esta ejecutando la instruccion.

Pero el resultado que arroja el programa es:

> Se llama a funcion funcion() en la linea 15
>
> 20
>
> Se llama a funcion sumar() en la linea 20

Es decir esta indicandome la linea donde se llamo originalmente a la funcion dentro de cada una de las funciones *funcion()* y *sumar()*, no indica la linea donde fue llamada realmente la funcion, que en realidad son las lineas 37 y 38.

*¿Como seria posible obtener la linea en la que se hizo el llamado a la funcion?* *¿Existe algun inconveniente en el macro **LINE** al incluirse en una funcion?* Puesto que se supone que el Preprocesador reemplaza estos valores antes de hacer la compilacion.

Agradezco de antemano por su ayuda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que tu estás buscando es una macro que te diga que la función ha sido llamada desde la línea X y eso no va a funcionar si llamas a la macro desde la propia función... Piensa que el mensaje se está generando en tiempo de compilación... el compilador en ese momento no sabe desde dónde vas a llamar a la función.

Para conseguir lo que pretendes deberías llamar a la macro **antes** de llamar a la función (o adaptar la macro para que la misma sea capaz de llamar a la función)... en cualquier caso no es algo demasiado práctico:

```
// "hack" para convertir el nombre de un parametro en una cadena
#define ___TOSTRING(x) #x
#define TOSTRING(x) ___TOSTRING(x)

#define dumpf(FUNC) \
    printf("Se llama a funcion %s() en la linea %d\n", TOSTRING(FUNC), __LINE__); \
    FUNC

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    /* Variables */
    int variableINT   = 45;
    char variableCHAR = 'A';
    char *variablePTR = "Hola Mundo";

    /* Debug de Variables*/
    dump(variableINT);
    dump(variableCHAR);
    dump(variablePTR);

    /* Debug de Funcion*/
    dumpf(funcion)(10);
    dumpf(sumar)(5, 5);

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Y el resultado sería:

```
La variable 'variableINT' ocupa 4 bytes
La variable 'variableCHAR' ocupa 1 bytes
La variable 'variablePTR' ocupa 4 bytes
Se llama a funcion funcion() en la linea 37
20
Se llama a funcion sumar() en la linea 38
5 + 5 = 10
```

Si te interesa tener las trazas de ejecución quizás deberías plantearte  aprender a usar el depurador de código... en programas tan pequeños como el que muestras no tiene demasiado sentido meter un sistema de trazas.

Comment: ¿No funcionaría también `printf("Se llama a funcion " __TOSTRING(FUNC) " en la linea %d\n", __LINE__); `?

Comment: También funcionaría, lo hice así por realizar un número mínimo de cambios.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster A mi me parece un detalle que no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta. Si la pregunta fuese sobre directivas del preprocesador quizás tendría algun sentido... en este caso con poder trazar las llamadas a las funciones le vale.

Answer (score 1):

> *¿Como seria posible obtener la linea en la que se hizo el llamado a la funcion?*

De ninguna manera. La información que buscas es el [stack trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace) el cuál es determinado en tiempo de ejecución mientras que las macros como `__LINE__` y `__FUNCTION__` son tokens que el [pre-procesador](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocesador) traduce en literales justo antes de compilar.

Es decir, la macro `__LINE__` escrita en la línea 100 será traducida por el literal 100 antes de compilar. La única manera sería pasando a cada función un parámetro indicando el punto de llamada:

```
void funcion(int argumento, int linea){
    printf("%d\nllamada en %d\n", argumento + argumento, linea);
}

void sumar(int a, int b, int linea){
    printf("%d + %d = %d\nllamada en %d\n", a, b, (a+b), linea);
}

/*09*/int main(void)
/*10*/{
/*11*/    funcion(1, __LINE__);
/*12*/    sumar(3, 2, __LINE__);
/*13*/    return 0;
/*14*/}
```

La llamada a `funcion(1, __LINE__)` sera traducida por el pre-procesador a `funcion(1, 11)` mientras que `sumar(3, 2, __LINE__)` será traducido a `sumar(3, 2, 12)`.

Tal vez estés pensando que te es suficiente y puedes usar parámetros por defecto... pero no funcionaría:

```
/*01*/void funcion(int argumento, int linea = __LINE__){
/*02*/    printf("%d\nllamada en %d\n", argumento + argumento, linea);
/*03*/}
/*04*/
/*05*/void sumar(int a, int b, int linea = __LINE__){
/*06*/    printf("%d + %d = %d\nllamada en %d\n", a, b, (a+b), linea);
/*07*/}

int main(void)
{
    funcion(1);
    sumar(3, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior, al pasar por el pre-procesador quedaría como:

```
/*01*/void funcion(int argumento, int linea = 1){
/*02*/    printf("%d\nllamada en %d\n", argumento + argumento, linea);
/*03*/}
/*04*/
/*05*/void sumar(int a, int b, int linea = 5){
/*06*/    printf("%d + %d = %d\nllamada en %d\n", a, b, (a+b), linea);
/*07*/}
```

Así que la salida del programa sería:

> ```
> 1
> llamada en 1
> 3 + 2 = 5
> llamada en 5
> ```

Lo cuál ya sabes que es falso, pues las funciones se llamaron en las líneas 11 y 12.

#### Conclusión.

Consulta la documentación de tu compilador para ver si puedes acceder al stack trace durante la ejecución del programa.